# python portfolio tracker

Tags: programming, portfolio-management, portfolio

any recommendations for a portfolio tracker that updates from csv ( or websocket but that would need to come with an active github and hopefully a man page).

New to python, mainly creating charts from csv that updates from websocket and running csv data through ta-lib indicators to add more lines to chart.  Some bash programming experience - if/then, user input type scripts.  hoping to get python feet wetter customizing someones existing project.

Answer (score 1):

There are pre-made free & open source solutions like [Portfolio Performance](https://www.portfolio-performance.info/en/) (PP), that allow to track portfolios, include certain indicators and provide extensive charts. Once you import a CSV with positions, the historical data will be automatically downloaded from Yahoo Finance or other data providers. However, PP is Java-based.

Or do you strictly require a custom python-based solution with custom charts (e.g. matplotlib)? If so, please provide a more concise description.

[image: Screenshot of Portfolio Performance]

Comment: Unfortunately this is not in Python...

Comment: Thats true, PP is Java based as stated above. The second paragraph reads to me, if Python and Bash were part of the skillset of the OP and not a necessity for a solution. However, the title is asking for a Python-based solution. That's why I asked for clarification.